# How to refresh radius circle using gmaps4rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I use gmaps4rails gem to show map in my rails app. There are parts where user can input location, within, and radius type.

**Example:**

```
location => Chicago, IL,
within => 10, 
radius type => km(kilometer).
```

I want to update marker and radius of the circle when user clicks "Update Review" link. I already replaced the marker using syntax below:

```
function add_marker(location_served) {
    var location = $(location_served).val();
    var geocoder;

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( {
        'address': location
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            Gmaps4Rails.replace_markers([{
                "description": "",
                "title": "",
                "longitude": results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                "latitude": results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                "picture": "",
                "width": "",
                "height": ""
            }]);
        } else {
            alert("The location you've entered is invalid");
        }
    });
}
```

But I don't have any idea about how to update the circle radius. I see `create_circle` method in `gmaps4rails.js`, but I don't know a parameter that should be passed when using that method.

Does anybody know how to update the circle dynamically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the circles aren't showing in the answer below is the tags for lat/lng:

```
//brute way to do
...
Gmaps4Rails.circles = [{"latitude":  , "longitude": , "radius":}];
```

Should be

```
Gmaps4Rails.circles = [{"lat":  , "lng": , "radius":}];
```

According to gmaps4rails.base.js line 165

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_marker(location_served) {
  var location = $(location_served).val();
  var geocoder;

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( {
    'address': location
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     Gmaps4Rails.replace_markers([{
        "longitude": results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
        "latitude":  results[0].geometry.location.lat()
     }]);

     //brute way to do
     Gmaps4Rails.clear_circles();
     Gmaps4Rails.circles = [{"latitude":  , "longitude": , "radius":}];
     Gmaps4Rails.create_circles();

     //soft way (if you only want to update radius)
     Gmaps4Rails.circles[0].google_object.setRadius(number_here); //beware in the latest version of the gem I replaced google_object with serviceObject 

    } else {
      alert("The location you've entered is invalid");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I add 'Gmaps4Rails.circles = [{"latitude": -122.214897 , "longitude": -122.214897, "radius": 10000}];
    Gmaps4Rails.create_circles();' but there are no circle,FYI, i use version 0.7.6. Thank for your next answer

Comment: Weird it already existed see https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/v0.7.6/public/javascripts/gmaps4rails.js  Well what's the error?

Comment: Hmm, there are no error message. But the circle didn't appear.